# How to access to a value which is in an array contained in an array typescript angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

In my oomponent, I have an array of array :

```
weekDays: Array<Array<{title:string, value:number, isChecked:boolean}>>;
```

The JSON structure of `weekDays` look like this :

[image]

How to access to (for example) the third value of `isChecked` of the the second array contained in `weekDays` ( weekDays[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzBrV.png) ), IN my HTML template.

Comment: Try `weekDays[1][2].isChecked`

Comment: Here's how: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kq17p3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add it by doing:

```
weekDays[1][2].isChecked or weekDays['1']['2'].isChecked
```